# Doubt with simple notations about set theory.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

**Definition.** We say a set $Y$ is inductive if $0 \in Y$ and, $\forall y \in Y, y^+ \in Y$, where $y^+$ is the sucessor of $y$, i.e., $y^+ = y \cup \{y\}$.

Define the set $\cal{A}$$ = \{B \in PA : 0 \in B \text{ is inductive}\}$. Then $\cal{A}$ is non-empty and from this set we form the natural number set, which is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\omega = \bigcap \cal{A}
\end{equation*}

After this, we've been given some properties and this is where my trouble begins.Take the following Lemma as an example:

**Lemma.** For all $n \in \omega$ e $m \in n$: $m \subseteq n$.

And my problems here are: What's the difference between $m \in n$ and $m \subseteq n$ ?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: $m\subseteq m$ but $m\notin m$

Comment: $\varnothing\subseteq\varnothing$, but $\varnothing\notin\varnothing$.

Comment: $2\in\{2,5,9\}$ but $2\not\subseteq\{2,5,9\}$.